# How can I refactor an enum so that it is still available in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity, refactoring

I am trying to use an enum so that it is available in the inspector. This code works:

```
public ArmorTypeEnum ArmorType;
public enum ArmorTypeEnum { Light, Medium, Heavy };
```

How can refactor it into a single line?

How can I make `ArmorTypeEnum` private while keeping `ArmorType` public?

Comment: You could make it internal in another Assembly, maybe. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make your enum anything other than public if you want `ArmorType` to be public too. See [Restrictions on Using Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx).

If you don't want to use an enum, and just want a selection in the inspector, you can use a [property drawer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) to show a selection of strings in the inspector.